# Fetch Non Matching result from MonogoDB Collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How I Can get the result set with IDs which are not there in MongoDB Collection.

Consider the below scenario :

I am passing 5 IDs Eg : [1,2,3,4,5] to check whether its exist or not in the collection.
out of 5, only 3 IDs are present [2,3,5]

then as a result, I should get [1,4]

Is there any way to achieve this with the help of aggregation or any other method in MongoDb.

Comment: this is actually a wrong approach to do this in mongodb query, you can do this in your client side language whatever you are using after query.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally just do it with some code, using `distinct` like so:

```
const ids = [1,2,3,4,5];
const existing = await db.collection.distinct('id', { id: { $in: ids } })

const output = ids.filter(i => !existing.includes(i))
```

You can also achieve this in a single call, but it has some overhead compared to this approach:

```
const ids = [1,2,3,4,5];

const output = db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            id: { $in: ids },
        },
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            ids: { $addToSet: '$id' },
        },
    },
    {
        $project: {
            ids: { $setDifference: [ids, '$ids'] },
        },
    },
]);
```